# Proving a variation of DCT

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

As homework, I was given the following problem.
Suppose $f_n\overset{\text{a.e}}{\rightarrow}f$, and for each $n$ there's a $g_n\in L^1$ satisfying $|f_k|\leq g_k$. Prove that if $g=\lim _n g_n$ is a.e defined, $g\in L^1$, and finally $\mu g_n\rightarrow \mu g$, then $\mu f_n\rightarrow \mu f$.

I thought about somehow using the triangle inequality, but I don't think that's right since the $f_n$'s and $g_n$'s might be far from each other. I thought about finding a dominating function for the $f_n$'s in terms of $g$, but I'm at a loss since $g$ may not dominate them and this does not use $\mu g_n\rightarrow \mu g$.
How to proceed?

Comment: What is $\mu g_n$? (And similarly for the other)

Comment: @T.Bongers $\mu f=\int _X fd \mu$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Fatou's lemma,

$$\int (g-f) \leq \lim\inf \int (g_n-f_n).$$
This means that

$$\int g - \int f \leq \lim\inf \int g_n - \lim\sup \int f_n,$$
and using the fact that $\int g_n \to \int g$ (this is also allows us to split up the $\lim\inf$). 
$$\lim \sup \int f_n \leq \int f.$$

Using $g_n+f_n$ instead of $g_n-f_n$ and using the same argument gives
$$\int f \leq \lim \inf \int f_n.$$

So $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int f_n = \int f$.

Comment: Very elegant. Thank you!